# How to interpret Q quality index from val.prob and compare different scoring rule results

Tags: predictive-models, validation, accuracy, scoring-rules

I'm interested in learning more about the Q value produced by `val.prob` in the R package RMS and how it compares with the Brier score. I understand Q, the quality index, is a variation of the logarithmic scoring rule that can be decomposed in useful ways, but I haven't been able to find guidance on:

--What values of Q are acceptable?
--What is the range of Q?
--How is Q related to the simple logarithmic scoring rule? Does the translation of the logarithmic score into Q make for easier interpretation? 
--In what cases is the Brier score or Q/logarithmic score preferred, and why might the conclusions these scores lead to differ?

I haven't been able to find great references to the Q score or discussions of the different aspects of accuracy measured by different scoring rules -- if you can provide such references those would be great to read too.

Answer (score 1):

Judging the magnitude of Q is not so easy.  But more information may be obtained at https://hbiostat.org/bib/papers/logistCal.pdf

The source code for `val.prob` gives the formula for Q but look at the above paper first.